# Как работает if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') { next() } ? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, middleware

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает и что именно делает этот кусочек кода

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    next()
}
```

Смотрю ролик по node.js для начинающих и в этом месте я очень плохо понимаю что происходит в коде

Ролик: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_aJdcDq6AY

Фулл код: https://github.com/utimur/profi_auth_with_roles_nodejs

Весь код в файле:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const {secret} = require('../config')

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        next()
    }


    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(403).json({message: 'User is not logged in'})
        }
        const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, secret)
        req.user = decodedData
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(403).json({message: 'User is not logged in'})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут реализуется midleware - это функция, которая работает на всех запросах перед вызовом хандлеров.

`next` это функция, в которой лежит  следующее мидлваре или вызов конкретного обработчика.

Для запросов OPTIONS вызов авторизации не требуется автору и поэтому вычисление токена на нем пропускается.

Надо бы ещё return, а то мне кажется обработка этого мидлваре пройдет дальше уже после ответа сервера клиенту.